# Running PowerShell commands simultaneously on the target machine with WinRM

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm trying to run multiple PowerShell commands simultaneously remotely on the target machine.

```
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
var runspacePool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(1, 10, connectionInfo);
runspacePool.Open();

var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
    powerShell.RunspacePool = runspacePool;
    powerShell.AddCommand("Some-long-running-command");
    var asyncResult = powerShell.BeginInvoke();
    waitHandles[i] = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle;
}

WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);            

runspacePool.Close();
```

How many processes and threads will be created on the target machine while executing this code? 
How can I create multiple threads on the target machine in one process/connection?